# Intersection of two prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose we have a commutative ring R with a 1. If we have two prime ideals of R, X and Y, where X ≠ Y, we know that it is not necessarily true that X∩Y = X or Y. However, can the generic statement be made that X∩Y ≠ X or Y, or is there a counterexample?

Comment: Let $R=k[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring in two variables. Then the ideals $(x)$ and $(y)$ are both prime in $R$ but their intersection $(x) \cap (y)$ is equal to $(xy)$, which is not equal to either of them.

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=k[x,y]$ be a polynomial ring in two variables. Then the ideals $(x)$ and $(y)$ are both prime in $R$ but their intersection $(x) \cap (y)$ is equal to $(xy)$, which is not equal to either of them, and for that matter not even prime.

Generally, if $X \cap Y=X$ or $X \cap Y=Y$ then obviously $X$ is contained in $Y$ or $Y$ is contained in $X$. This always happens only when the ideals in a ring are linearly ordered by inclusion, something that is true of valuation rings for example, but not for all rings.